# Two monitors - can I power down the unused second screen?

Tags: 13.04, multiple-monitors

I have a two monitor system and most of the time, I do not use the second monitor.

My question is, is there a way of blanking the second screen until I click a button or enter a command?

Why? To save power and keep my wife happy!

13.04 on a laptop with ViewSonic external screen.

Comment: check this... [Ubuntu Shell Script to Enable and Disable Secondary Monitor](http://danielj.se/2011/04/22/ubuntu-shell-script-to-enable-and-disable-secondary-monitor/)

Comment: Sort of works, but when the 2nd monitor starts up again, the mouse is limited to the second monitor as are all the windows!!! I'll play and let you know.

Comment: Brilliant, thank you. sorted it out with `--Right-of` rather than `--left-of`

Comment: @MrSeed Please, create a new answer mentioning all the procedures to do. So this question remains as *answered*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For those who have the same problems, the error was fixed using the comment on the question by MrSeed. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

If You power down a monitor the system doesn't understand Your action. All windows and cursor at the switched-off monitor stay invisible. You may

1. Before switching off start System settings -> Monitors (or Displays. I have Ukrainian interface). Select a monitor to switch off and press a switch near to it's name. It make a monitor blank and transfers all windows to another monitor
   or
2. Unplug the monitor from PC (it is not recomended for D-Sub). Maybe a problem with different voltages at PC and Monitor. I use this method at Notebook and HDMI monitor.

Comment: Thank you, The following suggestion worked for me: http://danielj.se/2011/04/22/ubuntu-shell-script-to-enable-and-disable-secondary-monitor/